# Why ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker extends AbstractQueuedSynchronizer

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I know some details regarding AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.
It is a framework for creating state dependent classes or synchronizer.
But I am not getting the point of extending this class in Worker of ThreadPoolExecutor.

```
private final class Worker extends AbstractQueuedSynchronizer implements Runnable
```

As seen by the signature of Worker class following things can be deduced:

1. When a new Runnable/Callable task is submitted, a new Worker object is created.
2. A new object of Worker can be considered as new thread.
3. `addWorker()` method will add new worker (or simply a task) and calls in itself `worker.start()` to start the thread.
4. Worker class is non-static nested class, hence it can access all variables of ThreadPoolExecutor
5. `run()` method of Worker class internally calls runWorker(this)

   public void run() {
       runWorker(this);
   }
6. `runWorker()` executes the actual task something like this:

   `void runWorker(Worker w) {
       try {
           w.lock();
           w.firstTask.run()
       } finally {
           w.unlock();
       }
   }`

AQS is used only for this lock and unlock of runWorker() method.
Can't we take a ReentrantLock here and keep Worker class simple?

Also class provide documentation regarding this, but I am unable to understand that :

> This class opportunistically extends AbstractQueuedSynchronizer to
>   simplify acquiring and releasing a lock surrounding each task
>   execution.  This protects against interrupts that are intended to wake
>   up a worker thread waiting for a task from instead interrupting a task
>   being run.  We implement a simple non-reentrant mutual exclusion lock
>   rather than use ReentrantLock because we do not want worker tasks to
>   be able to reacquire the lock when they invoke pool control methods
>   like setCorePoolSize.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer on your question is in the quote from [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) which your posted:

> We implement a simple non-reentrant mutual exclusion lock rather than
>   use ReentrantLock because we do not want worker tasks to be able to
>   reacquire the lock when they invoke pool control methods like
>   setCorePoolSize.

That's because **threads that might be waiting for tasks are indicated by not being locked**, i.e. `tryLock` returns `true` for them. And what could happen in this case if `ReentrantLock` will be used here: then it will be possible following sequence of actions:

`setCorePoolSize`->`interruptIdleWorkers`->`tryLock()` (here success!) -> `Thread.interrupt` (thread of  this worker)

which will cause worker interrupt itself.